# Vectors of a combined mesh have x,y,z values equal to zero

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am trying to combine two meshes. My code is shown below. The `CombineInstance` 'combine' have the correct values in its vertices. However, the combined mesh 'RetMesh' have all its vertices equal to (0,0,0). I don't understand what I am doing wrong.

I've read the tutorials I have find in the internet and I don't know what I am doing wrong.

```
void Start () {
    Mesh MM2 = testmeshfunc();
    GameObject GO;
    GO = new GameObject("MeshFromMPC", typeof(MeshFilter), typeof(MeshRenderer));
    GO.gameObject.transform.localScale = new Vector3(1, 1, 1);

    GO.gameObject.GetComponent<MeshFilter>().mesh = MM2;
}

Mesh testmeshfunc()
{
    Mesh RetMesh = new Mesh();

    Vector3[] V3A = new Vector3[4];
    Vector3[] V3B = new Vector3[4];
    int[] TrPtsA = new int[6];
    int[] TrPtsB = new int[6];

    Mesh mesha = new Mesh();
    Mesh meshb = new Mesh();

    var combine = new CombineInstance[2];

    V3A[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    V3A[1] = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
    V3A[2] = new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
    V3A[3] = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);

    TrPtsA[0] = 0;
    TrPtsA[1] = 1;
    TrPtsA[2] = 2;
    TrPtsA[0] = 2;
    TrPtsA[1] = 1;
    TrPtsA[2] = 3;

    mesha.vertices = V3A;
    mesha.triangles = TrPtsA;

    V3B[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
    V3B[1] = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
    V3B[2] = new Vector3(1, 0, 1);
    V3B[3] = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);

    TrPtsB[0] = 0;
    TrPtsB[1] = 1;
    TrPtsB[2] = 2;
    TrPtsB[0] = 2;
    TrPtsB[1] = 1;
    TrPtsB[2] = 3;

    meshb.vertices = V3B;
    meshb.triangles = TrPtsB;

    combine[0].mesh = mesha;
    combine[1].mesh = meshb;

    RetMesh.RecalculateBounds();
    RetMesh.RecalculateNormals();
    RetMesh.RecalculateTangents();

    RetMesh.CombineMeshes(combine);

    return RetMesh;
}
```

I am using Unity 2017.

Comment: First of all, your TrPtsA and TrPtsB arrays has length of 6 but you define only the first 3 values, the rest are zero. Also you need to recalculate bounds and normals for mesha and meshb before adding them for mesh combine. Try these and tell me if you still have issues.

Comment: Also forgot to add, do the RetMesh Recalculates after you have done the CombineMeshes() and put the trasnform Matrix in your CombineInstance, combine[0].transform = Matrix4x4.identity; and combine[1].transform = Matrix4x4.identity;

Comment: That solved it. I have previously tried all the things you've said except for the combine[0].transform = Matrix4x4.identity. What does that do? Why do we have to put add it. Thank you so much!

Comment: Its Transform matrix for the meshes before they get combined, so having Matrix4x4.Identity means the meshes are not affected. Probably you need it because otherwise it would transform with zero out Matrix which means all zeros you had, haven't tested it thought with Zero matrix to see if the results match.

Comment: Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction. I'll read further in to it.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, triangle index buffer set wrong. I though you are drawing plane then front face should be clockwise, this is yours

```
        V3A[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        V3A[1] = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
        V3A[2] = new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
        V3A[3] = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);

        TrPtsA[0] = 0;
        TrPtsA[1] = 1;
        TrPtsA[2] = 2;
        TrPtsA[0] = 2;
        TrPtsA[1] = 1;
        TrPtsA[2] = 3;

        mesha.vertices = V3A;
        mesha.triangles = TrPtsA;


        V3B[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        V3B[1] = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        V3B[2] = new Vector3(1, 0, 1);
        V3B[3] = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);


        TrPtsB[0] = 0;
        TrPtsB[1] = 1;
        TrPtsB[2] = 2;
        TrPtsB[0] = 2;
        TrPtsB[1] = 1;
        TrPtsB[2] = 3;
```

Code should be like this, I changed direction of index buffer as clockwise. if you don't make it clockwise, it won't appeared on screen by backface removal.

```
        V3A[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        V3A[1] = new Vector3(0, 1, 0);
        V3A[2] = new Vector3(1, 1, 0);
        V3A[3] = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);

        TrPtsA[0] = 0;
        TrPtsA[1] = 1;
        TrPtsA[2] = 2;
        TrPtsA[0] = 2;
        TrPtsA[1] = 3;
        TrPtsA[2] = 1;

        mesha.vertices = V3A;
        mesha.triangles = TrPtsA;


        V3B[0] = new Vector3(0, 0, 0);
        V3B[1] = new Vector3(0, 0, 1);
        V3B[2] = new Vector3(1, 0, 1);
        V3B[3] = new Vector3(1, 0, 0);


        TrPtsB[0] = 0;
        TrPtsB[1] = 1;
        TrPtsB[2] = 2;
        TrPtsB[0] = 2;
        TrPtsB[1] = 3;
        TrPtsB[2] = 1;
```

Comment: I am fine with the rotations of the vertices. My main issue was when I combine the meshes, all the vertices in the combined mesh have values equal to (0,0,0). The solution was commented on the original post above. Thanks.